# Spring MVC import css and js in jsp page

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I caught an issue when I add a css file into jsp file, I have searched and try the tut in the following link but it not work for me...http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

My project have been created by spring tool suite. Here are my file structure and the files

```
-\src
-----\main
--------\webapp
-----------\resources
--------------\css
-----------------\jquery-ui.css
--------------\js
-----------------\jquery-1.10.2.js
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="vn.edu.tdt.controller" />



</beans:beans>
```

abc.jsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I know that my problem have asked in stackoverflow.com by many people and I have read those and try it but it's not working, so a straight answer is very helpful :D

UPDATE question : 
I've got this message in my browser :

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/tdt/resources/css/jquery-ui.css".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced similar issue, I tried to implement the spring part from the below page and it worked,

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

The mvc:resources mapping is the key concept.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You should map your static resource path like this

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

and switch from relative to root referencing in the path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/jquery-ui.css">
```

also and add an order attribute to you resource mapping. Something like

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" order="0" />
```

move your scan statement to be the first in xml, so, something like

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="vn.edu.tdt.controller" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    ...
```

the reason for the suggested change is that static mapping have the lowest precedence by default, and setting it to 0, actually makes it higher, and you're not getting an error message saying that it can't be mapped, rather that you're not getting a CSS resources. This means that probably some request mapping is taking over a request (which you should see in the logs)

Comment: Master Slave : I have try your advice and it not work either. My browser display a message : " Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/tdt/book/resources/css/jquery-ui.css". "

Comment: I've made a slight edit and fixed a typo, with your edited questio nthe only thing that can cause issues is that you're using a relative path in your JSPs.

Comment: yes, I have read and try the tut in http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: can you reach your css by any of the url in the updated question?

Comment: Master Slave : No, I can reach my css file by those URLs.

Comment: with respect to the structure you've posted, the mapping is OK, I've suggested another change in the edited response.

Comment: I think the problem is the message of my browser "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/tdt/resources/css/jquery-ui.css".", I have include css and js in jsp page before, but I have never seen it occur.

Answer (score 0):

Include resources in your context like this:

```
<resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**"/>
<resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
```

And link in jsp page:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/css/jquery-ui.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<c:url value="/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure the image,css and js folder like below

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="WEB-INF/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="WEB-INF/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="WEB-INF/js/" />
```

Comment: thank for your suggestion but it's not accordant with my file structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

I used the mvc:resouces and other stuff as mentioned in above responses. Still faced the issue finally removed the '/' and that worked for me..